# cloudera impala PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION

Tags: cloudera, parquet, impala

It is possible to configure Cloudera Impala (5.12) to default to `name` instead of `position` for `PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION`?

My Parquet files don't always have the same set of columns so we need Impala to look them up by name rather than position, and its a bit of a pain to do this in Hue for every session:

```
set PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION=name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the info Amos,

I posted the same question on the Cloudera forums and they pointed me to a way to configure this thru the Cloudera Manager.

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/PARQUET-FALLBACK-SCHEMA-RESOLUTION/m-p/62318#M3883

Comment: Great. I wasn't aware of the `-default_query_options` flag :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this isn't configurable on Impala side.

```
  case TImpalaQueryOptions::PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION: {
    if (iequals(value, "position") ||
        iequals(value, to_string(TParquetFallbackSchemaResolution::POSITION))) {
      query_options->__set_parquet_fallback_schema_resolution(
          TParquetFallbackSchemaResolution::POSITION);
    } else if (iequals(value, "name") ||
               iequals(value, to_string(TParquetFallbackSchemaResolution::NAME))) {
      query_options->__set_parquet_fallback_schema_resolution(
          TParquetFallbackSchemaResolution::NAME);
    } else {
      return Status(Substitute("Invalid PARQUET_FALLBACK_SCHEMA_RESOLUTION option: "
          "'$0'. Valid options are 'POSITION' and 'NAME'.", value));
    }
    break;
  }
```

Impala server doesn't set default query options. All options are set where client session is setting up. So you need to configure whatever the client you are using.  See `shell/impala_shell_config_defaults.py` for instance.

However, you can still modify the code and recompile :)

in `common/thrift/ImpalaInternalService.thrift`

```
struct TQueryOptions {
    ....
    // Determines how to resolve Parquet files' schemas in the absence of field IDs (which
    // is always, since fields IDs are NYI). Valid values are "position" (default) and
    // "name".
    43: optional TParquetFallbackSchemaResolution parquet_fallback_schema_resolution = 0  <--- change it to 1
    ....
}
```